# Update relations of one to many

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    logs = db.relationship("Logs", uselist=False, backref="user")

class Logs(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users_user.id'))
    ...
```

---

Both ways will work. Basically my question is about the preferable and why. I am talking about this because in my current work i am using always the second option, and i need to decide if is needed to refactor to make the code like the first example.

---

```
logs = Logs()
logs.user = current_user._get_current_object()
```

---

```
logs = Logs()
logs.user_id = current_user.get_id()
```

Comment: You could just say `current_user.id`. Either ways work fine and as far as I know, you might be able to just do `logs.user = current_user` also.